# How can i make menu close with the same key it was open?

Tags: tampermonkey

You use the esc key to open the menu with keycode 27 but how can i make the menu close using the same key esc* aka keycode 27 instead of having to click outside the menu. Do I have to make another event to close menu?

```
document.head.appendChild(styleItem1);

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        if (modal.style.display = "none") {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
})

var modal = document.getElementById("simpleModal");
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

function closeModal() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}
function outsideClick(e) {
    if (e.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison

Comment: Replace `=` with `==` in your second `if`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for the help now i know that = is to assign a value to a variable and == is to compare two variables